# How to make go-ipfs use ws-star for punsub

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe, p2p, ipfs, libp2p

When i use wss in `go-ipfs`, it throw not support wss

so i can’t use
`/dns4/ws-star.discovery.libp2p.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p-websocket-star`

i wanna make js-ipfs and go-ipfs can join same pubsub topic

does any other address can make it
or how can make go-ipfs support it

Comment: I dont think go-ipfs supports `wss`. Checkout this issue : https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/issues/3907

Answer (score 1):

> i wanna make js-ipfs and go-ipfs can join same pubsub topic

To make it possible you only need to ensure JS is connected to GO.

There is no ws-star for go-ipfs because it has DHT.
JS version has no DHT yet, but can work around that by letting it know about your GO node by adding it to bootstraps:

1. Enable WebSockets transport (`/ws`) in go-ipfs config:

   - Add `/ip4/A.B.C.D/tcp/4422/ws` to `Addresses.Swarm` array and restart the node – it  will enable unencrypted WebSockets
2. Put it behind nginx or some other reverse proxy that provides TLS (enabling encrypted Websockets, `/wss`)

   - You need TLS because JS loaded from HTTPS requires WebSockets connections
3. Set up `/wss` address of go-ipfs in js-ipfs as one of bootstrap servers.

   - This will ensure go and js have direct connection and no DHT is needed.

Comment: i can't use direct connection in my use case